# Re-share YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

This person has uploaded and removed and re-uploaded a lot of videos.

I want to download the videos before the person removes the videos again.  I want to upload the videos back to YouTube to save hard disk space and ensure the videos can be watched from multiple computers.

What is the efficient way to handle this? Downloading the videos and then uploading them back on YouTube seems longer way to accomplish something so simple.

Comment: First of all, do you have the permission of the original uploader to re-share his/her own videos?

Comment: I thought about that, and I decided I might just make the videos private. The reason I want them on youtube is to save hard disk space and viewable on any computer (as long as username and pwd are there).

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of a faster way. I would download the videos with Firefox [Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/3006/) extension (you just right-click on status bar and download), and then maybe not use YouTube, but a similar service (as you don't mind about SEO, etc, and is more about just having them available).

I'd use [Viddler](http://www.viddler.com), as in my tests, it does not re-compress an FLV and should show at the same quality (no loss) that you downloaded from YouTube. Download Helper usually will let you download the several resoloutions flvs available.

However, the involved procedure of re-uploading to YouTube might bring a loss in quality.

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting advice on how to illegally download content that pertains to YouTube and this is a clear violation of their terms of service which you agreed to as a user.

It is against YouTube's terms of service to download clips or videos in any way shape or form, even for offline usage or private usage. That's why after many years they now created YouTube RED which gives several additional privileges.

Every YouTube video is uploaded with a Standard YouTube license which means that the video is only available as it is, through the platform. Now, you can try checking the creative commons section.

The Creative Commons license means that you can use the content with the online video editor (www.youtube.com/editor) to edit parts of the video to create a new video. Even if you don't want to edit the video, this option allows you to download the video to your computer or cellphone and re-upload to other channels, so check if the creator has such videos available under the Creative Commons editor. If not then no, you can't download his content for your own private usage.